# Python-Need labels to repeat

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner at Python, and I have been trying to practice the basics for some of my work tasks.

I managed to use pandas to combine multiple datasets and it worked! But now I want the labels: *item no, item, category and category code* to repeat for different companies. Is there a way I can get this out of Python?

I left an image of the problem (see below).
[image: problem goes here]

Thanks in advance for any advice.

See code to combine datasets below:

```
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.chdir(r"C:\\Users\\justi\Documents\\MyName\\Analysis\\Database") 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True) 
        df.head() 

df.to_excel('newcombined.xlsx')
```

Comment: can you give us your code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.